# Cannot read property 'next' of undefined using BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

**I'm having this isue only when i deploy to android (didn't tried on iOS)**, if i run ionic serve to view if all is fine, console doesn't throw me any error and working fine!, but when i try it in android, i have the issue:

> Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

ok, let's make a description, first of all, i'm using the integrated ionic starter template side_menu, i have made some style modifications, (but only that), so let's view each component needed to reproduce this issue:

**app.component.html**:

here i only put an ionDidClose event in the ion-menu element, (other things in the document are not neccesary at all):

```
<ion-menu class = "shorted_menu" (ionDidClose) = "setDisplayMenuInfo('basicInfo')">
    <!--More code here...-->
</ion-menu>
```

in **app.component.ts** i have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx';
import { AppPages } from '../global_modules/app_pages';
import { showInfo, setComponentBehaviorSubject } from '../global_modules/menu_functionality';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

enableProdMode();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

    public appPages;
    public showInfo;
    public currentDisplayMenu = 'basicInfo';
    public behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<string>;
    public behaviorSubjectObservable: Observable<any>;
    public behaviorSubjectSubscription: Subscription;
    public setComponentBehaviorSubject;

    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private oneSignal: OneSignal,
        private storage: Storage,
        private router: Router,
        public menu: MenuController
    )
    {
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    async setup(){

        this.appPages = AppPages.pages;
        this.showInfo = showInfo;
        this.setComponentBehaviorSubject = setComponentBehaviorSubject;

        this.userData = await this.getUserData();
        this.userAvatar = this.userData.data.avatar_src.src && this.userData.data.avatar_src.src != "" ? 
                        `${this.imagesRoute}${this.userData.data.avatar_src.src}`:
                        this.userAvatar;

        this.behaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('basicInfo');
        this.behaviorSubjectObservable = this.behaviorSubject.asObservable();
        this.setComponentBehaviorSubject(this.behaviorSubject);

        this.behaviorSubjectSubscription = this.behaviorSubjectObservable.subscribe(data =>{

            this.currentDisplayMenu = data;

        });

    }

    ionViewWillLeave(){

        this.behaviorSubjectSubscription.unsubscribe();

    }

    setDisplayMenuInfo(str){

        this.showInfo(str);

    }

    async getUserData(){

        return await this.storage.get('session_storage');

    }

    clearUserSession(){

        this.oneSignal.removeExternalUserId();
        this.storage.set('session_storage', null);

    }

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
            this.setup();

            if(this.platform.is('cordova')){

                this.setupPush();

            }

            this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res)=>{

                if(res == null){

                    this.router.navigateByUrl('log-in');

                }

            });

        });
    }

    setupPush(){

        this.oneSignal.startInit(oneSignalData.appId, oneSignalData.googleProjectNumber);
        this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);

        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => {

            //Do something when notification received...
            /*let msg = data.payload.body;
            let title = data.payload.title;
            let additionalData = data.payload.additionalData;*/

        });

        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(data => {

            let additionalData = data.notification.payload.additionalData;
            //Actions to take when notification opened...

        });

        this.getUserData().then(res =>{

            if(res && res.data.username != "" && res.data.type_user != ""){

                this.oneSignal.setExternalUserId(`${res.data.username};${res.data.type_user}`);

            }else{

                this.oneSignal.removeExternalUserId();

            }

        })

        this.oneSignal.endInit();

    }

}
```

where AppPages is simply another class imported by app.component.ts and inside i having the public static property pages, this is simply an array of objects, and inside each object i have some menu display properties, like the title and icon of each menu item, also, having another property, called detailTag, this tag allows me to easily show or hide some content of the menu depending to the property:

```
currentDisplayMenu
```

of app.component.ts, so some menu info is clasified by 'basicInfo' inside detailTag property, this means that when currentDisplayMenu have content 'basicInfo', i will only show the menu items that have the detailTag matching by 'basicInfo', the other clasification is 'accountInfo'.

Well, other file that is needed is **menu_functionality.ts**, which looks like:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

var componentBehaviorSubject:BehaviorSubject<string>;

export function showInfo(tag){

    switch(tag){

      case 'basicInfo':
        return componentBehaviorSubject.next('basicInfo');
        break;
      case 'accountInfo':
        let CBS = componentBehaviorSubject.next('accountInfo');
        this.menu.open();
        return CBS;
        break;

    }

}

export function setComponentBehaviorSubject(behaviorSubject:BehaviorSubject<string>){

  componentBehaviorSubject = behaviorSubject;

}
```

The reason of why i'm calling the this.menu.open(); function only when the tag is 'accountInfo', is because, the app.component.html and app.component.ts are working globaly in the app and if the user clicks only in the sidemenu button to open it there is no problem and no need to put it, but here is the thing and the real reason of why i'm using BehaviorSubject:

- App.component.html and app.component.ts are shared, so there are no problems if the user hits in the menu opener button in one or other page of the app, but... the way i'm showing other info like 'accountInfo' is using an avatar which is not inside of app.component.html (is not shared) i wanted to put in another place instead of putting it in the menu, this is because i didn't know how to make it globally usable like app.component.html, so i have to write that html in each page.html that i want to use it.

and when user hits the avatar i need to only show the 'accountInfo' items in the menu and obviously open it, (this is why i only call this.menu.open when the tag is accountInfo), i don't know if there is another better way to make this.

Comment: seems `showInfo` is being called before `setComponentBehaviorSubject`

Comment: but that not explains why is working fine without any errors when i use ionic serve... so i don't think that...

Comment: Ohhh other thing that i forgot to mention is that this example is working fine (but with errors), in my android 9 (displays and works correctly the info and open the menu when clicks the avatar), but does not working on android 8 and below... the error is the same as this title.

Comment: @Riven have you tried to invert the two calls `showInfo` and `setComponentBehaviour`, as @Jaromanda X suggested? I believe that you are overthinking: `ComponentBehaviourSubject`is null, that's it

Comment: Ohhh sorry yeah!, i'm going to do it and see if this works, sorry for overthinking jejeje

Comment: Hmmm this is strange, i did that, but i realized that i having this menu issue only if i have not logged in in my app yet, if i was already logged in the app, the menu is working as expected without errors... but if i haven't logged in and try to log-in the menu will works fine after reseting the app...

Comment: i'm going to edit question and put the entire code of app.component.ts, may be is something that i'm not viewing in app.component.ts i'm suspecting the issue is in app.component.ts...